# jython sricpt: How to modify the maximum connection of connection pool under Websphere MQ Connection factories

Tags: python, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I have two connection factories under `Resources ->JMS ->Connection Factories`.

1) ConnectionFactory

2) IntegrationConnectionFactory

I want to modify the maximum Connection of connection pool under both the connection factories.
`Resources ->JMS ->Connection Factories -> ConnectionFactory -> Connection Pool -> Maximum Connection`.

Can someone please help  me to write Jython script to modify the maximum connection of connection pool under connection Factories.

Comment: Please someone help me to fix it

Comment: Rather than ask the community to write the script for you, you're more likely to get the help you're seeking if you post a script that you've written that is not working.  If you don't know where to start, you should ask that specific question and someone will likely chime in with pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example,

```
wsadmin>confactory = AdminConfig.getid('/J2CConnectionFactory:ConnectionFactory/')

wsadmin>conpool = AdminConfig.showAttribute(confactory, 'connectionPool')

wsadmin>AdminConfig.modify(conpool, '[[maxConnections 50]]')

wsadmin>print AdminConfig.showall(conpool)
[agedTimeout 0]
[connectionTimeout 180]
[freePoolDistributionTableSize 0]
[maxConnections 50]
[minConnections 1]
...
```